# Reject certain subdomains on port 80 on nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a few domains/subdomains, and I have a `server` block to properly redirect them to port 443. But what I'm also trying to do is for a couple of those subdomains, I don't want it to connect at all on port 80.

So below is an example of the values I'm redirecting to port 443.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name ~^(?<subvar>sub1|sub2|sub3|sub3)\.example\.com$;

    return 301 https://$subvar.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

So I also have a `sub4.example.com` which I don't want to connect at all on port 80, but when I try to access it, I get the nginx 404 not found message, what I wanna achieve is a "server not found" sort of message.

Let me know if you'd like more information, or if I'm missing anything.

Comment: you can use error_page directive to display custom message as there is no "server not found" inbuilt message in nginx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't listen on port 80 for these domains
- Return nginx's special HTTP code [`444`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) in a default vhost.

> ```
> server {
>     listen 80 default_server;
>     return 444;
> }
>
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name ~^(?<subvar>sub1|sub2|sub3)\.example\.com$;
>     return 301 https://$subvar.example.com$request_uri;
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi Xavier, sorry about the late reply. So if we try to connect using port 80, and nginx rejects it using 444, will the data have been transmitted insecurely already? What I have is some of the hosts are allowed to be redirected from 80 to 443, but I want to reject the connection of other hosts.

Comment: @Samer No, the 444 code is a special feature of nginx instructing him to close the connection thus it doesn't send any data whatsoever.

Comment: @XavierLucas I stuck with configuring DynDNS for my local. May you look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304810/domain-name-for-my-pc-configure-router-how-to please? Thanks!